# Invalid parameter for sklearn estimator pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am implementing an example from the O'Reilly book "*Introduction to Machine Learning with Python*", using Python 2.7 and sklearn 0.16.

The code I am using:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), LogisticRegression())
param_grid = {"logisticregression_C": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100], "tfidfvectorizer_ngram_range": [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Best cross-validation score: {:.2f}".format(grid.best_score_))
```

The error being returned boils down to:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter logisticregression_C for estimator Pipeline
```

Is this an error related to using Make_pipeline from v.0.16? What is causing this error?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There should be two underscores between estimator name and it's parameters in a [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)
`logisticregression__C`. Do the same for `tfidfvectorizer`

It is mentioned in the user guide here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#nested-parameters.

See the example at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compose-plot-compare-reduction-py

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once. The __ did the trick. Thank you

Comment: file not found in this link: `http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-compare-reduction-py`

Comment: This link is broken. Therefore provides NO answer.

Comment: @mccurcio Updated the link. Even without the example links, the answer is adequate in itself.

Comment: @mccurcio Yes I agree. The former comment was just in reponse to "NO answer" part.

Answer (score 25):

For a more general answer to using `Pipeline` in a `GridSearchCV`, the parameter grid for the model should start with whatever name you gave when defining the pipeline. For example:

```
# Pay attention to the name of the second step, i. e. 'model'
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
     ('preprocess', preprocess),
     ('model', Lasso())
])

# Define the parameter grid to be used in GridSearch
param_grid = {'model__alpha': np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)}

search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid)
search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

In the pipeline, we used the name `model` for the estimator step. So, in the grid search, any hyperparameter for Lasso regression should be given with the prefix `model__`. The parameters in the grid depends on what name you gave in the pipeline. In plain-old `GridSearchCV` without a pipeline, the grid would be given like this:

```
param_grid = {'alpha': np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)}
search = GridSearchCV(Lasso(), param_grid)
```

You can find out more about GridSearch from this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/automatic-hyperparameter-tuning-with-sklearn-gridsearchcv-and-randomizedsearchcv-e94f53a518ee?source=your_stories_page-------------------------------------).

Answer (score 8):

Note that if you are using a pipeline with a voting classifier and a column selector, you will need multiple layers of names:

```
pipe1 = make_pipeline(ColumnSelector(cols=(0, 1)),
                      LogisticRegression())
pipe2 = make_pipeline(ColumnSelector(cols=(1, 2, 3)),
                      SVC())
votingClassifier = VotingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('p1', pipe1), ('p2', pipe2)])
```

You will need a param grid that looks like the following:

```
param_grid = { 
        'p2__svc__kernel': ['rbf', 'poly'],
        'p2__svc__gamma': ['scale', 'auto'],
    }
```

`p2` is the name of the pipe and `svc` is the default name of the classifier you create in that pipe. The third element is the parameter you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `model.get_params().keys()` [ in case you are using only model ] or `pipeline.get_params().keys()` [ in case you are using the pipeline] to get the keys to the parameters you can adjust.

Comment: This is the only solution helped me to solve same problem. In my case, I had to replace `max_depth` with `selectfrommodel__estimator__max_depth` found in `pipeline.get_params().keys()`